# How to truncate menu label in wordpress?

Tags: menus

I want to truncate the menu label to 10 characters, and if the header label is more then it will show 10 characters followed by ...
For example:
Menu Title: ABCDEFGHIJKLMN
It should display the label as ABCDEFGHIJ...

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the filter `nav_menu_item_title` is what you're after. Here's an example to use that to truncate the title to 10 characters. This is untested, but should do what you want, added to e.g. your `functions.php`

```
    function filter_nav_menu_item_title( $title, $item, $args, $depth ) { 
        $truncLength = 10;
        if (strlen($title) > $truncLength) {
            return substr($title, 0, $truncLength) . "...";
        } else {
            return $title;
        } 
    }
         
    // add the filter 
    add_filter( 'nav_menu_item_title', 'filter_nav_menu_item_title', 10, 4 );
```

Does that do it?